# Fork() in an IF statment in UNIX

Tags: unix, fork

What I understand about fork() is that once the child process created by it, it knows nothing about the code that was exsited before that point we reached "fork()".
But in if statments with multiple fork() it seems like the child process is doing the argument calculation even though it came before it's fork() creator.

For example:

```
int main ()
{
if((fork())==(fork()))
   printf ("Hello.\n");

printf ("Bye.\n");
return 1;
}
```

There would be a sum of 4 process including the father. In the child process (I will call it d) that was created by another child process, the fork() that created our d process is the second fork() in the if statement.

Even though that the first fork() shouldn't be familiar to d, it is my understanding that d process calculates that 0==0 and print "Hello" (the output is correct for sure).I have two questions:

1.How is it that the d process even able to reach the first fork() in the if statement that came before the fork() that created this d process (the second one) ?

2.Why in that point that we are in the d process does the first fork() equals to 0 if it happens only in the child process that was created by this specific fork() (the father of d) ?

Comment: _"once the child process created by it, it knows nothing about the code that was exsited before that point we reached 'fork()'"_ Why/how would that be? Can you explain your beliefs in more detail?

Comment: My understanding is that the child process should start running on the code that comes after the fork(), I thought  that it should do nothing with what came before it..

Comment: The process has been cloned. It's at the same point in the same program with the same data in memory (except for the return value for the `fork()` call). Why would its history be unavailable and how then would it be able to proceed with the program in the new process? What would it do?

Comment: This are abiously solid points, I am only learning this subject which is new to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I understand about fork() is that once the child process created in knows nothing about the code that was existed before that point we reached "fork()".

The child is an exact replica of the parent, apart from the return value of `fork()`. This includes all run-time state, including the memory and the CPU registers. That's all the memory the processes have, so they "remember" the same things.

Let's rewrite your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t a = fork();
    pid_t b = fork();
    if (a == b)
        printf ("Hello.\n");
    printf ("Bye.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

After the forks, there are four processes, the original one has `a != 0 && b != 0` (and `a != b` since its two children are distinct), two others have one of `a` and `b` zero, and the fourth has `a == b == 0`. The last one is the only one where `a == b`, so that one runs the conditional `printf()` call.

Comment: So, it remembers that in the state that came before his creation, the first fork() (his father fork()) was equal to 0 ?. Is it responsible to check after the if statement even though that normally we are not looking back on the previous code before it's fork () ?

Comment: @BenJ, yes. By the point the second `fork()` is called, the return value of the first one is stored somewhere in the process's memory or registers. (it doesn't matter if it's stored to a named variable, or as an unnamed temporary value, the value needs to be somewhere so that the comparison can be done)

Comment: And it is his responsiblity to check after the if statement even though that normally we are not looking back on the previous code before it's fork () ?

Comment: @BenJ, I'm not sure what you mean with that second question

Comment: Each and every process checks the entire if statement , is that correct ?

Comment: @BenJ, yeah, they all run the same code, just with different values for the PID's `a` and `b`. You could put something like `printf("%d %d\n", (int) a, (int) b)` before the `if` and you'd see the values they've got. (That of course only works with the named variables, and the output lines from different processes will get intermixed)